# JQuery Default text on empty text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I have a email form text box that while it is empty I would like it to have the value "E-Mail" And when you click on it the text goes away. If someone clicks on it and doesn't enter text. on Blur I would like for it to return to having the default text.

I have been trying a few things but nothing is working. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 20):

Or you could just use the placeholder html5 attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword" placeholder="Type keyword here" />
```

Comment: Didn't know about the placeholder attribute. Great addition! :) It's a shame IE doesn't support it at the moment (IE 9).

Comment: Does one still consider IE to be a web browser??

Comment: By now the placeholder attribute is supported by all browsers: https://caniuse.com/input-placeholder (even IE!)

Answer (score 9):

it goes something like this

```
$('#yourElement').focus(function(){
    //Check val for email
    if($(this).val() == 'E-Mail'){
        $(this).val('');
    }
}).blur(function(){
    //check for empty input
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).val('E-Mail');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use the placeholder attribute and then us this jquery as backup for IE

```
<input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword" placeholder="The watermark" value='The watermark' class="watermark"/>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.watermark').focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }).blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[It's pretty straightforward.](http://jsfiddle.net/sdleihssirhc/QUEaf/) Just erase the value `onfocus`, and then (if the value is still empty) refill it `onblur`.

Comment: The example also removes newly entered text in the input field, which is not what you'd want.

Answer (score 1):

Call the below function and pass it two args: slightLabel(jQuery('#email_field'), 'email');

```
  function slightLabel(input, text) {
        jQuery(input).val(text);
        jQuery(input).data('defaultText', text);
        jQuery(input).focus(function(){
            if(!jQuery(this).data('touched'))
            {
                jQuery(this).data('touched', true);
                jQuery(input).val('');
            }
        });

        // the part to restore the original text in
        jQuery(input).blur(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).val() == '')
            {
                jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).data('defaultText'));
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the watermark plugins of jquery that do just that. I use a watermark plugin that has the following code

```
$.fn.watermark = function (c, t) {
var e = function (e) {
    var i = $(this);
    if (!i.val()) {
        var w = t || i.attr('title'), $c = $($("<div />").append(i.clone()).html().replace(/type=\"?password\"?/, 'type="text"')).val(w).addClass(c);
        i.replaceWith($c);
        $c.focus(function () {
            $c.replaceWith(i); setTimeout(function () { i.focus(); }, 1);
        })
            .change(function (e) {
                i.val($c.val()); $c.val(w); i.val() && $c.replaceWith(i);
            })
            .closest('form').submit(function () {
                $c.replaceWith(i);
            });
    }
};
return $(this).live('blur change', e).change();
```

};

Callable in jquery by setting the class of the input textbox to watermark like this

```
<input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword" class="watermark" style="width: 250px"
    title="Type keyword here" />
```

The title is what will be displayed in the watermark.

Answer (score 1):

Use this [Jquery-placeholder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) plugin

Using this plugin makes it possible to also use the placeholder attribute in non HTML5 capable browsers.