# ASP.NET implementing a search box like stackoverflow search box

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use VS2010,C# to develop an ASP.NET web app, I'm going to implement a search box like the one used in Stackoverflow (or other sites), initially there is a phrase (for instance "search") in the search text box, when user click in text box, its text is emptied and user can type his phrase, but if he leaves the text box (lost focus) empty, again the phrase "search" is displayed, how can I implement this nice effect?

thanks

Comment: just check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770585/jquery-default-text-on-empty-text-box

Comment: don't be scared of JQuery, jQuery IS 100% pure cross browser solid JavaScript. Other solutions eventually break on some browsers unless you test in all of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" 
    onblur="javascript:if(this.value=='') this.value= this.defaultValue;" 
    onfocus="javascript:if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" 
    id="txtSearch" 
    value="search" 
    name="txtSearch" />
```

Comment: What if I want to search for `search`?

Comment: you are right!, of course I don't have this problem in my own database but I think that a problem of this method!, thanks for your answer

Comment: I prefer to use pure javascript as I'm a bit scared of JQuery!

Comment: @Ali_dotNet: This is a nasty un-reusable read-impairing solution... makes me feel ill just looking at it. Plus Curt has a great point, you just end up with a buggy feature

Comment: It's like eating christmas turkey in April. It used to be good, but now its old and dry, and I'm enjoying my easter eggs.

Comment: you are right Curt, I know this method is old, but my problem is that I'm know familiar with JQuery, I must first try to learn it, and I know this is a MUST for me, as JQuery can help me a lot, thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2):

This is the textbox watermark plugin which I use:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

I then created the following code which uses the `title` attribute for the watermark text for all elements with the `.textbox_watermark` class

```
var Textbox_Watermark =
{
    init: function () {

        var textboxWatermarks = $(".textbox_watermark");

        for (var i = 0, ii = textboxWatermarks.length; i < ii; i++) {
            $(textboxWatermarks[i]).watermark(textboxWatermarks[i].title);
        }
    }
}

Textbox_Watermark.init();
```

Then when focus is on the textbox, the watermark is removed.

You will need the [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) framework for this to work

Comment: You can also do it by using Textbox watermark extender in the client side ajaxcontroltoolkit.You can have look at [this](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little script I use for just this purpose. It does required [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) though, but if that is an option for you then give it a try. (there is probably a javascript alternative for this too, but I dont know it)

```
function addInputBlur(selector, text) {
    var element = $(selector);

    element.blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val(text);
            $(this).addClass("InputBlur");
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("InputBlur");
        }
    });
    element.focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == text) {
            $(this).removeClass("InputBlur");
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });

    element.blur();
}
```

**Note**: the "selector" param should be a JQuery selector value (i.e. "#MyTextbox")

Also, the "InputBlur" CSS class is just the style I use for the grey/italic font

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the view source for stack overflow and what i notice is that they have a attribute named **placeholder**

```
<div id="hsearch">
                <form id="search" action="/search" method="get" autocomplete="off">
                <div>

                    <input autocomplete="off" name="q" class="textbox" **placeholder="search"** tabindex="1" type="text" maxlength="140" size="28" value="">
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

try this it works for mozilla ,, check for others

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in JavaScript using a function similar to this one:

```
        /*
         * applyDefaultValue() - Takes a DOM object and it's string value as paramters, when the element
         * is focussed, the 'value' is blanked out, ready for user entry. When the item is blurred, if nothing was typed
         * then the original value is restored.
         */
        function applyDefaultValue(elem, val) {
            elem.value = val;
            elem.onfocus = function() {

                if (this.value === val) {
                    this.value = ''; //On focus, make blank
                }
            }

            elem.onblur = function() {
                if (this.value === '') {
                    this.value = val; //If it's not in focus, use declared value
                }
            }
        }
```

You can then apply this to items like this:

```
        /*
         * Onload function to set the default 'email address'/'search' value and blank out the password field
         */
        window.onload = function() {
            applyDefaultValue(document.getElementById('email'), 'Email Address');
        }
```